# .NET CustomValidator: Prevent Submit Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to add a custom field validator to some legacy code. If the email does not belong to a certain domain, it should prevent the form from firing.

Here is my markup.

```
<asp:Textbox id="tbEmail" autocomplete="off" CssClass="txt260" runat="server" TabIndex="1"></asp:Textbox>          
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="rfvEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="Required" CssClass="ValidatorError">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator id="cfvEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" CssClass="ValidatorError" OnServerValidate="tbEmail_CustomValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="regExpEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid" CssClass="ValidatorError"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

...

```
<asp:Button ID="bSubmit" Text=" CREATE ACCOUNT " CssClass="NewButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="DisabledUpdateButton()" OnClick="bSubmit_Click" />
```

Here is the C# code:

```
protected void tbEmail_CustomValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    List<string> approvedEmailDomains = new List<string>()
    {
        "domainnameihid.com"
    };

    if (!approvedEmailDomains.Any(x => tbEmail.Text.EndsWith(x)))
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

When I write an invalid domain name, the code falls into args.IsValid = false. Once args.IsValid is false though, it still continues to fire the submit button. Required and Regular field validators do not. How do I get the CustomValidator to prevent the button's OnClick from firing or proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create client side validation also. You do that with `ClientValidationFunction` of the Validator.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbEmail"
   ClientValidationFunction="allowedDomains" ErrorMessage="Not Valid"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function allowedDomains(sender, element) {
        var approvedDomains = ['<%= string.Join("', '", approvedEmailDomains) %>'];
        element.IsValid = $.inArray(element.Value, approvedDomains) > -1;
    }
</script>
```

For this to work you need a `public` List

```
public List<string> approvedEmailDomains;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    approvedEmailDomains = new List<string>()
    {
        "domainnameihid.com",
        "stackoverflow.com"
    };
}
```

Comment: So if I do this on the client side, why does the server side validation accomplish?

Comment: I see, so in ServerValidation even though args.IsValid is false it won't actually stop until the Postback, which wouldn't trigger until after the Button's OnClick?

Comment: Yes. That it what it means. So in order for a better user experience do both client AND server validation since client side can be ignored by a user if they disable javscript.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I just tried this solution and it does prevent click, but it no longer accepts my valid domain. I put "test.com" as an approvedEmailDomain with the same javascript but when I try to put in a @test.com it tells me Invalid Email

Comment: Later this evening I can look into updating the answer. But you could also try to tweak it yourself. The important thing is using a `ClientValidationFunction` with a return of `element.IsValid` true or false.